# How to change swiper slide carousel in swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I'm struggling with changing swiper slide carousel in cover flow.

This is what I got for now.

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-aboutus', {
  // Optional parameters
  effect: 'coverflow',
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  initialSlide: 0,
  keyboardControl: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  lazyLoading: true,
  preventClicks: false,
  preventClicksPropagation: false,
  lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  coverflow: {
    rotate: 0,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 250,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: false,
  }
})
```

```css
.swiper-container-aboutus {
  height: 500px;
}

.swiper-slide{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 490px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: 0ms;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 490px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row swiper-container-aboutus">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

It functions but I would like to change carousel to look like this:

[image]

I have tried by adding this piece of code:

```
.swiper-slide{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 490px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: 0ms;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 490px;
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
}
```

I added `transform: rotate(45deg) !important;` to transform the slides in diamond shape and they were transformed, but with that I have lost builtin swiper.js `translate3d()` function.

Is that possible with Swiper.js to edit slides it that way and still have cover flow working as it should?

Any other tips are greatly welcomed.

**EDIT**

When I put

```
loop:true;
centeredSlides: true,
slidesPerView: 3,
initialSlide: 2,
```

My cover flow starts from left side and not from middle like I would like.
Why is that? On photo you can see it, and when I click for next one it shifts to right side.

[image]

Is it possible to start centered? I though that this `centeredSlides: true` will do it.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-aboutus', {
  // Optional parameters
  effect: 'coverflow',
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  initialSlide: 0,
  keyboardControl: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  lazyLoading: true,
  preventClicks: false,
  preventClicksPropagation: false,
  lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  coverflow: {
    rotate: 0,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 250,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: false,
  }
})
```

```css
.swiper-container-aboutus {
  height: 200px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 0ms;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
}

.slide-content {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row swiper-container-aboutus">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

[image: tadaa!]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks great when I run code snippet and it's just what I was looking for. But when you run code snippet and take it to full screen it looks different. That is how it looks for me when I copy code and past it to my project. Do you know why?

Comment: In this snippet i didn't take care of dimensions, i think that's the problem. Adjust width/height

Comment: Yes, that is first that I have tried but everything brakes form me. I think that width is bothering because it gets overwritten with swiper.js width.

Comment: Sure it gets overwritten, there's no other way for a Swiper to adjust items according to slidesPerView' value. Read about configuring Swiper, i think it will help you

Comment: I have looked in documentation https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#parameters but not able to fix it. I also updated my question if you can have a look.  Do you have any advice, would appreciate a lot! Thanks!